# Magento change quantity shown for mobile only

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, jquery, phtml

I have this code here to show me a product collection. Currently shows me 12 on desktop and mobile. I would like to keep it at 12 on desktop. And only 5 on mobile devices.

Code is below and the part in question is $this->setProductsCount(12) ;

```
<?php 
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
//$query = 'SELECT cid FROM tees_user_login_table where ((group_id = 1 and status = 1 and cid > 0) or (group_id in (2,3,4,5) and include_new = 1 and status = 1))';
$query = 'SELECT cid FROM tees_user_login_table where status = 1 and include_new = 1';
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
$categoryIds = array() ;
foreach($results as $k=>$v) {
    $categoryIds[] = $v['cid'] ;
}
$this->setProductsCount(12) ;
$this->getProductsCount() ;
$_productCollection = $this->getProductCollection()->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','price','special_price','sku','small_image'))
    ->joinField('category_id',  // add category ID field to collection
        'catalog_category_product',
        'category_id',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        null,
        'left')
    ->groupByAttribute('sku')   
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile` for checking **current device is mobile**.

```
$IsCurrentDriveMob=Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match($userAgent=Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent(),
                                                     $server=$_SERVER);
$this->setProductsCount(12) ;                                                            
if($IsCurrentDriveMob){
    $this->setProductsCount(5) ;
}
```

Comment: Does this work well when caching is enabled? I can imagine this will only work when the block is never cached.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this using CSS, since it's rather easy and makes it possible to have exceptions for specific pages or specific screen sizes. You need to load 12 products at all times, but with CSS you'll make sure only the first 5 will be visible to the visitors.

The way I'd do this is by using this code snippet:

```
ul li:nth-child(n+6) {
    display:none;
}
```

Of course you'll need to make this class more specific using a media query and the correct class for your products grid/list, but the `:nth-child(n+6)` will be your answer.